# process_vm_readv returns EPERM when binary has no read attribute

Tags: linux, system-calls

I have two simple test programs:

- First program allocates a **buffer** and goes into endless loop
- Second program is using `process_vm_readv` to read the content of that **buffer**

It works fine until I remove read attribute from first binary. I am doing something similar to this:

```
$ chmod -r prog1
$ ./prog1 &
pid=19382 buf_addr=0xbfaef000
$ ./prog2 $(pidof prog1) buf_addr
errno=EPERM /* Operation not permitted */
```

It was tested on RHEL 7.2 and a standard user account (no problem on root account).

Why/how `chmod -r` on one binary makes its process memory not accessible from another process via `process_vm_readv`? I see no difference in permissions of memory pages so I wonder how it works.